# How to make this function faster: algorithm to create chain based on even and odd numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, while-loop, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

in Python I would like to write a function that returns the number from a number set that leads to the longest sequence created based on a calculation algorithm ("*if n is even divide by two else multiply by three and add one*"). F.e. for the number 3, the sequence would be *3-> 10 -> 5 -> 16 -> 8 -> 4 -> 2 -> 1*.

My attempt of writing a fast, non naive function:

```
def my_fun(n):
    dici = {k: v for k, v in zip(range(n), range(n))}
    count = 0
    while (len(dici)>1):  
       count += 1        
       dici = {k:(v/2 if v%2 == 0 else v*3+1) for k,v in {key: dici[key] for key in dici if dici[key] > 1}.items() }
    while all(value != 1 for value in dici.values()):
       dici = {k:(v/2) for k, v in dici.items()}
       count +=1
    return dici, count
```

With the input of 10, the function returns 9 as the number leading to the longest chain (length 19).

As I would like to apply my function to greater numbers, this version is way too computationally extensive. Is there any way to shorten my code?

Comment: Interesting alternative to memoisation.

Comment: Why do you expect this to be faster than a naïve implementation, need or want it to be fast?

Comment: You can read up on the Collatz conjecture for ideas.

Answer (score 1):

- floating point arithmetics & comparison for equality is dangerous: use `//`
  (got a non-ending loop for 7)
- just dividing by two when just one start value is left may be incorrect
- For every argument *s* smaller than `n//2`, there is one twice as large taking one step more:
  Start with

```
def ulam(n):
    """ return start, length of the longest sequence starting lower than n. """
    dici = {k: v for k, v in zip(range(n//2, n), range(n//2, n))}
    count = 0
    while dici:  # len(dici)>1):  
        count += 1
        start = next(iter(dici))
        dici = {k:(v//2 if v%2 == 0 else v*3+1) 
                    for k,v in dici.items() if v > 2 }  # > 1 }
        # print(dici, start)
    return start, count
```